# Changing one property of ThemeData.dark()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a theme that can be changed. `ThemeData.dark()` and `ThemeData()` . I want to change the default `accentColor` 's value of the `ThemeData.dark()`. Is this possible? My codes in `main` are like this:

```
theme: snapshot.data
          ? ThemeData.dark()
          : ThemeData(
              accentColor: Colors.white,
              canvasColor: Colors.blue[400],
              appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color: Colors.blue[400])),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! ThemeData has a method called copyWith where you can copy the original and assign new values to only those you want to change. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
ThemeData.dark().copyWith(accentColor: Colors.black)
```